# How to send / Receive mail with "qmail" in PHP

Tags: php, qmail

i want to send and receive mail using qmail in php.
i have never used it before tell me how is it possible.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

It is just another MTA. You configure PHP to send mail through it as you would any other SMTP server.

To handle incoming mail with PHP either have qmail deliver it somewhere and then poll that location, or get an MDA (such as procmail) that can pass incoming mail through a PHP script.

Comment: how can i assign receiving location to qmail ??

Comment: Configuring your system to use qmail to receive mail is entirely a matter of setting up qmail and your DNS. It has nothing to do with PHP or programming (so it off-topic for Stack Overflow). You could ask on Server Fault, but you'd probably be better off starting with the qmail manual.